# keyboard communication protocol?

Tags: encryption, encoding

I'm analyzing the transmitted data from the apple Smart Keyboard to the iPad, and I have troubles arriving to a conclusion:

When I press a key, the keyboard transmit two blocks of data: the identification address (I think, it is always the same) and the key data divided in 4 bytes. It sends the same information when I release the key.

The key data I recorded was:

```
press   'b': 11011101 10001000 01011100 11100010
release 'b': 11011101 01001000 01011100 01001000
press   'b': 11011101 11001000 01011100 01101011
release 'b': 11011101 00101000 01011100 00011101

press   'c': 11011101 10101000 01011100 00111110
release 'c': 11011101 01101000 01011100 10010100
press   'c': 11011101 11101000 01011100 10110111
release 'c': 11011101 00011000 01011100 10101111

press   'd': 11011101 10011000 01011100 10001100
release 'd': 11011101 01011000 01011100 00100110
press   'd': 11011101 11011000 01011100 00000101
release 'd': 11011101 00111000 01011100 01110011
```

As you can see, the first and the third bits are always the same, independent of the key, and the second byte is a counter, in big-endian format.
I guess that the last byte is actually carrying the information about the exact key pressed, but since it's different every time, my first thought was that the byte is somehow encrypted with the counter.

Any suggestion on how can I obtain the information about the key?

Comment: This is off-topic here, (Requests for analyzing ciphertext, finding hash preimages, identifying or decoding some code, or even reviewing full cryptographic designs are off-topic, as the results are rarely useful to anyone else and/or would be too long for this site.) If you want to see what is the data see [Introduction to the Security of Apple Pencil and Apple Smart Keyboard](https://gsec.hitb.org/materials/sg2018/WHITEPAPERS/A%20First%20Look%20Into%20The%20Security%20of%20The%20Apple%20Pencil%20and%20the%20Apple%20SmartKeyboard%20-%20Stefan%20Esser.pdf) by Stefan Esser

Comment: Thank you for the comment @kelalaka, I have already read the document you linked, but unfortunately it does not contain useful information about the topic, it just describes the firmware

Comment: Note that if the fourth byte is actually encrypted, then no good encryption algorithm will leak anything about the key or message contents.

Comment: @ArtemGlukhov how did you capture the transmitted data?

Comment: @Babydesta with a logic analyzer connected as "cable in the middle", and pressing keys while capturing

Comment: does it make a difference whether you give it a quick press or press it for a few seconds? I'm interested in the question that's why I'm asking such a stupid questions.

Comment: My suggestion would be to press the same key 256 times (enough for the counter to wrap), and see if the data is the same for the counter

Comment: good idea poncho. @ArtemGlukhov would you please capture more data and post it on gist github

Comment: Thank you for the idea, @poncho! Tomorrow I will try and I will post it

Comment: @Babydesta [https://gist.github.com/artemglukhov/96927295e9e1291059211642fead6520](key 'A') pressed many many times. The output is formatted as:

-press 'a'    -> BC ...

-                 -> BB ...

-release 'a' -> BC ...

-                 -> BB ...

Comment: Edit: the link is [this](https://gist.github.com/artemglukhov/96927295e9e1291059211642fead6520), can you add a bit detailed description of the data columns on the gist

Comment: @Babydesta I did add a description of the columns on the gist, as a comment, below the file.

I will add there all the information I'm finding